# How to backup a specific SQL Server Schema's table?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, schema

In my SQL Server database, I have multiple schemas. I would like to backup only a specific schema's tables to a format that can easily be restored.

Example:

- [dbo].[Trucks]
- [dbo].[Cars]
- [unknown].[Trucks]
- [unknown].[Cars]

How can I backup only the schema `[unknown]`'s tables and be able to restore them easily?

Also, is it possible to backup a specific schema from a `.bak` file that contains the entire database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, unless the schema or table(s) reside on their own filegroup.

SQL server only supports backups at the database level or at the filegroup/file level, not at the table (or at any other object's) level.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx